Am I using return render(request, url) wrong in django? (CS50)
In Project 1 of Web Development with Python and Javascript with CS50, I made a form class that should create a new wiki page.
It's supposed to get the input before using its "action" to trigger a function which will return to the home page from the addpage page once it's done. But using return render() to send the input and other necessary information while redirecting to the home page (something that has worked fine in other functions) doesn't seem to work this time. There's a brief reload and the input just disappears, there's no redirect, and the util.save_entry() hasn't created a new page.
Could someone give me a hint where I might've went wrong please?
Thanks.
The page for adding new pages
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{%block head%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
{%endblock%}

{% block body %}
    <h1>New Page</h1>
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <form action = "{% url 'addpage' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{title}}
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

My urls:
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:page>", views.getpage, name="page"),
    path("addpage", views.addpage, name="addpage")
]

addpage function in views:
def addpage(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        title=NewTitle(request.POST)
        if title.is_valid():
            newtitle = title.cleaned_data["title"]
            util.save_entry(newtitle, "This is a new entry")
            return render(request, "encyclopedia\index.html", {
                "entries": util.list_entries(),
                "form":Search()
            })
            #make index change when it receives newtitle
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/addpage.html", {
            "form":Search(),
            "title":NewTitle()
        })

I've tried changing it to an HttpResponseRedirect, but the way the lecture in CS50 does it just doesn't seem to work here.
I've also fiddled with a lot of other stuff like the form content itself, seeing if the request was the problem, asking other sites.
The main problem is it's not redirecting to the index page.

Are you sure that the form is valid?

As far as I understand, you want to create an instance of the page and redirect to this page.
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def getpage(request, page):
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, link=page)
    enter code here

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/page.html", {
            "page":page,
             enter code here
        })

def addpage(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        page=PageForm(request.POST)
        if page.is_valid():
            page.save()
            return redirect(reverse("page", kwargs={"page": page.link})
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/addpage.html", {
            "form":PageForm(),
        })

And also the path("str:page", views.getpage, name="page") should be placed at the very end of your URLs. This is because the page URL might coincide with some of your static URLs and override the main URLs.
And be sure to set the field link to unique=True
